# how to print space contain attribute in Perl Script

Tags: perl

I have some data in input file

```
user date="" name="" id="small"
user date="" name="" id="sample test"
user date="" name="" id="big city"
```

I want to get only id's from above file

code::-

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input = "location\input.txt";
open("FH","<$input") or die;
while(my $str = <FH>)
{
   my @arr = split(/ /,$str);
   $arr[2] =~ s/id=//g;
   $arr[2] =~ s/"//g;
   print "$arr[2]\n";
}

close("FH");
```

Output :

```
small
sample
big
```

Note :: Here I'm not able to print complete word like "small test", "big city"

Expectation : I need to get complete word "sample test" and "big city" anyone please help me on this

Comment: Your code doesn't behave like you say it does. You are using `$arr[3] =` instead of `$arr[3] =~`, `S/"//g` instead of `s/"//g`, `split(/ /, ...` instead of `split(/ +/, ...`. Please, show us a sample a code that's 1) working, and 2) reproduces your issue.

Comment: sorry my mistake it is

Comment: Backslash in the path string inside a double quoted string will not work. You should only copy/paste code into questions. Not type it in. The code you post must be exactly the way it was when you encountered a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the format will always have quotes after `id`, you can do:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, "<", "location/input.txt" or die $!;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
  my ($id) = $line =~ /id="(.*?)"/;
  say $id;
}
```

Breaking down that complicated line we have:

- `$line =~ /id="(.*?)"/`: match `id="..."` and grab the smallest possible
  `...`. If you use `.*` instead, you will grab up until the last " of the line, which might belong to another field. This is not the case for `id`, but try it with `date` and you'll see.
- `my ($id) = ...`: process the regex match in *list context*, which returns the capture groups, and assign it pairwise to the list `($id)`. Concretely, this stuffs the matched value in `$id`
- `say $id`: prints `$id` with an automatic newline after it.

Comment: Tried this but still getting the same

Comment: The idiomatic way to capture text inside quotes is probably `"([^"]*)"`.

Comment: @Noor When I run the above code with the sample input, it gives the expected output. You need to elaborate and explain why it does not work for you, or else no one can help you any further.

Comment: Sure, but that's more typing and the difference (extra backtracking) usually does not matter. Good remark though.

Comment: Two people are telling you this code works. Either your input is not what you said it is, or you're not testing this code.

Comment: I re-tested it and this code *really* does produce `small`, `sample test`, and `big city`. I could upload a screenshot but I don't see how that will convince you the code works.

Comment: When running this code, I get the expected output: "small", "sample test" and "big city". If you're not seeing that, then there's something that you're not telling us.

Comment: I have updated the question can you please check now with updated data

Comment: Same (correct) output. It looks like you removed a few spaces, but my solution does not care about spaces between fields.

Comment: but I'm not getting the expected output I too running the same code

Comment: Please double-check that your input is the same as in your post, and that you _are actually running the code I gave you_.

Comment: I literally copy-pasted the code from here to my system to test for you. Two other people have done the same and confirm that it produces the correct output given the input you provided. You are clearly doing something different, so figure out what that is. The code is fine.

Comment: Sorry, everything is fine from my side but still not getting expected output

Comment: Try running `perl` by itself and then copy-paste the answer into it. End with ctrl-z. That should ensure you are not accidentally running old code.

Comment: "([^"]*)"..do I need to add this pattern in my code?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm able to getting desired output

Comment: @Noor: Do Accept the answer if it solves your problem. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

A nice module for handling quoted strings is [`Text::ParseWords`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Text::ParseWords). It is a core module too, making it even handier. You can use it here to easily split the string on whitespace, then parse the result into hash keys.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Text::ParseWords;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my %data = map { my ($key, $data) = split /=/, $_, 2; ($key => $data); } quotewords('\s+', 0, $_);
    print Dumper \%data;
}

__DATA__
user  date=""  name=""  id="small"
user  date=""  name=""  id="sample test"
user  date=""  name=""  id="big city"
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'user' => undef,
          'name' => '',
          'date' => '',
          'id' => 'small'
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'name' => '',
          'date' => '',
          'id' => 'sample test',
          'user' => undef
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'id' => 'big city',
          'date' => '',
          'name' => '',
          'user' => undef
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

A simplified version to extract data of interest

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

while(<DATA>) {
    my %d = /(\w+)="(.*?)"/g;
    say 'id: ' . $d{id};
    say Dumper(\%d);
}

__DATA__
user date="" name="" id="small"
user date="" name="" id="sample test"
user date="" name="" id="big city"
```

Output

```
id: small
$VAR1 = {
          'date' => '',
          'id' => 'small',
          'name' => ''
        };

id: sample test
$VAR1 = {
          'id' => 'sample test',
          'date' => '',
          'name' => ''
        };

id: big city
$VAR1 = {
          'name' => '',
          'id' => 'big city',
          'date' => ''
        };
```